# Issue to place a picture below a DIV

Tags: html, css

how could I center the girafe picture **below** the orange DIV? Many thanks

See: http://jsfiddle.net/0qLevh83/7/

[image]

```
  <img class="type-de-soins" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-g-267-153-4.jpg">


.desc p {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.desc {
  float: right;
  width: 40.8%;
  background-color: rgb(196, 196, 196);
}

.desc-box {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 350px;

  background-color: rgb(226, 96, 18);
}

.desc-box-text {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.38;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.desc-soins {
  float: left;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.38;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.type-de-soins {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  z-index: 4;
  width: 179px;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 13px;
  margin-left: 23.25%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.desc-soins strong {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but tables are really handy when you want to do columns. You can do the same design with a table with much less CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `position: relative` to `.desc-box clearfix` instead of `absolute`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.type-de-soin a:first').css({
    'background-color': '#B4D454',
    'color': '#fff'
  });

  $('.type-de-soin a').click(function() {
    var region = $(this).attr('data-region');

    $('.type-de-soin a').css({
      'background-color': '#fff',
      'color': '#3A7CDB'
    });
    $(this).css({
      'background-color': '#3A7CDB',
      'color': '#fff'
    });

    $('.textzone:visible').stop().fadeOut(500, function() {
      $('#' + region).fadeIn(500);
    });

    return false;

  });

});
```

```css
#carte-des-soins {
  background: #ccc;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
#carte-des-soins ul {
  list-style: none;
}
#carte-des-soins li {
  display: inline;
}
#description-des-soins {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
#soins-1,
#soins-2,
#soins-3,
#soins-4 {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding: 5px 20px 20px 20px;
  color: #333;
  font: 12px'Open Sans', "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1px;
  background: red;
}
#soins-1 h3,
#soins-2 h3,
#soins-3 h3,
#soins-4 h3 {
  color: #3A7CDB;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 18px;
}
#soins-2,
#soins-3,
#soins-4 {
  display: none;
}
#soins-2 p {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#soins-1 p {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
#soins-1 a {
  color: #3A7CDB;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#soins-1 a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.desc p {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.desc {
  float: right;
  width: 40.8%;
  background-color: rgb(196, 196, 196);
}
.desc-box {
  position: relative;/*change position to relative*/
  z-index: 1;
  width: 350px;
  float: left;/*use float left*/
  background-color: rgb(226, 96, 18);
}
.desc-box-text {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.38;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
.desc-soins {
  float: left;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.38;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
.type-de-soins {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  z-index: 4;
  width: 179px;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.desc-soins strong {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="carte-des-soins">
  <ul>
    <li><span class="type-de-soin"><a href="#" data-region="soins-1"> Soins 1</a></span>

    </li>
    <li><span class="type-de-soin"><a href="#" data-region="soins-2"> Soins 2</a></span>

    </li>
    <li><span class="type-de-soin"><a href="#" data-region="soins-3"> Soins 3</a></span>

    </li>
    <li><span class="type-de-soin"><a href="#" data-region="soins-4"> Soins 4</a></span>

    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="description-des-soins">
  <div id="soins-1" class="textzone">
    <div class="desc-box clearfix">
      <p class="desc-box-text">Eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim. Quinta decima eodem modo typi qui nunc nobis videntur parum, clari fiant sollemnes. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis assum typi. Nulla facilisis at vero eros et
        accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui. Eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse. Etiam processus dynamicus qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum mirum est. Claritatem Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius,
        quod ii legunt.</p>
      <img class="type-de-soins" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-g-267-153-4.jpg"><!-- move inside div --> 
    </div>
    <div class="desc clearfix">
      <div class="desc-soins">
        <p><strong>PHYT'S : soin visage Equilibre&nbsp;</strong>
          <br>60 min.&nbsp;</p>
        <p>Type de peaux : toute peau à équilibrer (grasse, mixte ou sèche). Soin du visage traditionnel, personnalisé selon le type de peau, qui vous fera retrouver une peau saine et un teint éclatant.&nbsp;</p>
        <p><strong>PHYT'S : soin visage Pureté active</strong>

          <br>60 min.&nbsp;</p>
        <p>Type de peaux : peaux grasses ou mixtes comédogènes. Soin spécifique visant à assainir le teint, éliminer les comédons et aider à réguler les excès de sébum. Ce soin s’effectue, de préférence par cure de 4 soins avec l’application au préalable
          d’une crème spécifique pendant quelques jours.&nbsp;</p>
        <p><strong>PHYT'S : soin visage Aqua Phyt's
</strong>
          <br>75 min.&nbsp;</p>
        <p>Soin très hydratant à l'Acide Hyaluronique d'origine végétale&nbsp;</p>
        <p><strong>PHYT'S : soin visage Capyl
</strong>
          <br>60 min.&nbsp;</p>
        <p>Type de peaux : peaux sèches à rougeurs diffuses, sensibles, fines. Soin calmant et décongestionnant, spécialement conçu pour les peaux sensibles ou à rougeurs diffuses.&nbsp;</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="soins-2" class="textzone">
    <p>L'eau minérale</p>
  </div>
  <div id="soins-3" class="textzone">
    <p>Les personnes</p>
  </div>
  <div id="soins-4" class="textzone">
    <p>Les fgd</p>
  </div>
</div>
<p></p>
<br>
<p></p>
<br>
<p></p>
<br>
```

If you can't change html structure then with pure css:

```css
#carte-des-soins {
  background: #ccc;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
#carte-des-soins ul {
  list-style: none;
}
#carte-des-soins li {
  display: inline;
}
#description-des-soins {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
#soins-1,
#soins-2,
#soins-3,
#soins-4 {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding: 5px 20px 20px 20px;
  color: #333;
  font: 12px'Open Sans', "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1px;
  background: red;
}
#soins-1 h3,
#soins-2 h3,
#soins-3 h3,
#soins-4 h3 {
  color: #3A7CDB;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 18px;
}
#soins-2,
#soins-3,
#soins-4 {
  display: none;
}
#soins-2 p {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#soins-1 p {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
#soins-1 a {
  color: #3A7CDB;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#soins-1 a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.desc p {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.desc {
  position: relative;
  width: 40.8%;
  background-color: rgb(196, 196, 196);
  float: right;
  margin-top: -225px;
}
.desc-box {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 350px;
  float: left;
  background-color: rgb(226, 96, 18);
}
.desc-box-text {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.38;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
.desc-soins {
  float: left;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.38;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
.type-de-soins {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  z-index: 4;
  width: 179px;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  clear: left;
}
.desc-soins strong {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<div id="carte-des-soins">
  <ul>
    <li><span class="type-de-soin"><a href="#" data-region="soins-1"> Soins 1</a></span>

    </li>
    <li><span class="type-de-soin"><a href="#" data-region="soins-2"> Soins 2</a></span>

    </li>
    <li><span class="type-de-soin"><a href="#" data-region="soins-3"> Soins 3</a></span>

    </li>
    <li><span class="type-de-soin"><a href="#" data-region="soins-4"> Soins 4</a></span>

    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="description-des-soins">
  <div id="soins-1" class="textzone">
    <div class="desc-box clearfix">
      <p class="desc-box-text">Eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim. Quinta decima eodem modo typi qui nunc nobis videntur parum, clari fiant sollemnes. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis assum typi. Nulla facilisis at vero eros et
        accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui. Eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse. Etiam processus dynamicus qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum mirum est. Claritatem Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius,
        quod ii legunt.</p>

    </div>
    <img class="type-de-soins" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-g-267-153-4.jpg" />
    <div class="desc clearfix">
      <div class="desc-soins">
        <p><strong>PHYT'S : soin visage Equilibre&nbsp;</strong>
          <br>60 min.&nbsp;</p>
        <p>Type de peaux : toute peau à équilibrer (grasse, mixte ou sèche). Soin du visage traditionnel, personnalisé selon le type de peau, qui vous fera retrouver une peau saine et un teint éclatant.&nbsp;</p>
        <p><strong>PHYT'S : soin visage Pureté active</strong>

          <br>60 min.&nbsp;</p>
        <p>Type de peaux : peaux grasses ou mixtes comédogènes. Soin spécifique visant à assainir le teint, éliminer les comédons et aider à réguler les excès de sébum. Ce soin s’effectue, de préférence par cure de 4 soins avec l’application au préalable
          d’une crème spécifique pendant quelques jours.&nbsp;</p>
        <p><strong>PHYT'S : soin visage Aqua Phyt's
</strong>
          <br>75 min.&nbsp;</p>
        <p>Soin très hydratant à l'Acide Hyaluronique d'origine végétale&nbsp;</p>
        <p><strong>PHYT'S : soin visage Capyl
</strong>
          <br>60 min.&nbsp;</p>
        <p>Type de peaux : peaux sèches à rougeurs diffuses, sensibles, fines. Soin calmant et décongestionnant, spécialement conçu pour les peaux sensibles ou à rougeurs diffuses.&nbsp;</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="soins-2" class="textzone">
    <p>L'eau minérale</p>
  </div>
  <div id="soins-3" class="textzone">
    <p>Les personnes</p>
  </div>
  <div id="soins-4" class="textzone">
    <p>Les fgd</p>
  </div>
</div>
<p></p>
<br>
<p></p>
<br>
<p></p>
<br>
```

Also check my comments in code.

Answer (score 1):

Place the image below < p class="desc-box-text" > but inside < div class="desc-box " >

Should look like this

```
<div class="desc-box ">

    <p class="desc-box-text">Eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim. Quinta decima eodem modo typi .......</p>

    <img class="type-de-soins" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-g-267-153-4.jpg">

</div>
```